# How to Represent three term school year in school portal

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been given a project to design a school portal, But I have encountered problem on how to implement the school year.

In a school there, there are three terms, and for each term every student would have a test exam (40 marks) and the main exam (60 marks). The problem I am facing is with how to design the database table and also call the table automatically from my php code. This is what i did.

I created the `test` table and called it `2013_test` and the exam table `2013_exam`, each table have `student_id`, `course_id`, and `term_of_yr` fields.

So when the PHP code tries to query the table in mysql: this is what I do

```
<?php
   $term = date('Y');
   $sql  = "SELECT * FROM ".$term."_exam";
?>
```

But the  problem I am facing is that the first term starts from `September` to `December`, and second term from `january to April`, the third term `May-June`, hence the problem, as the year changes so does the table name from the code, so when am supposing to be looking into the `2013_exam` table in year `2014` the code would be reading `2014_exam`. I have been thinking on how to  redo this to something better, but it has not been easy, that is why am here, I need help on how to implement this please

Comment: "I created the test table and called it 2013_test" That was your first mistake ;-)

Comment: call it the 2013-2014 school year instead. Plus, your design should have a SINGLE table "test", and store the dates in a field within it. There's very few reasons to have multiple related tables and key them by name.

Comment: No. You only need one table for every school year ever

Comment: One table okay, but I would like to keep the history of all students, so that they can come check their past performance

Answer (score 0):

Instead of naming your table by the year, add a column to contain the year. Plus, table names shouldn't start with numbers, unless you are quoting them in your select query, which given your code above you aren't

```
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM '".$term."_exam'";
```

Answer (score 0):

## Hold your horses right there son

Listen to what the comments are saying:

- you only need one table for all this data
- the term/period/whatever is a column of the table

The only reason you'll need different tables is to store data that is unrelated. For example:

- a table various seemingly homogeneous events (sports, cultural...)
- a table for keeping students
- oh well, I think you get the picture

So term grades is all a single homogeneous looking set of data. Leave it in a single table, that way you can query by date to filter data. You can also setup a script for backing up data by date and then prune your tables if the info is no longer needed live

Good luck in your endeavour, it sounds like a lot of fun ^^